# primeng p-checkbox loses value but ngModel is the same

Tags: angular, primeng

Using primeNg v12 and I have this `p-checkbox` inside a `ng-template` (home comes from `let-history`)

```
<p-checkbox #homeSelection [value]="history.home" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();"                               
[(ngModel)]="checkedHomes">    
</p-checkbox>
```

`#homeSelection` is declared as

```
 @ViewChildren('homeSelection') homeSelection: QueryList<Checkbox>;
```

When I select a table row, the table data reloads and all previous checkbox selections are lost, but checkedHomes doesn't change, so I don't know how to "reassign" every value as it was before selecting the row (why have a two-way ngModel if it does not sync automatically on table refresh and assigns the correct values?)

I have been playing with ChangeDetectorRef as well, but p-checkbox value property is reseted every time

Any suggestion?